# Is there a way to list all macros defined in a Twig template?

Tags: php, twig

I got a twig template A which basically consists of a number of twig macros.
I include that template in another twig template B.
Can I somehow list all the macros defined in template A in template B?
If not can this be done using the PHP controller?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack it in `twig` by creating a custom class that extends `Twig_Template`
It feels a bit dirty but it works roughly .

*Do note: `Twig` prefixes every macro you make with `get` so if you have an `{% macro getField .... %}`, it will display `getgetField` with the current solution.*

```
abstract class Template extends \Twig_Template {
    public function getDefinedFunctions() {
        return array_diff(get_class_methods($this), array_merge(['getDebugInfo', 'getDefinedFunctions'], get_class_methods('\Twig_Template'), get_class_methods('My\ProjectName\Here\Template')));
    }   
}
```

Register custom Template class into `twig`

```
<?php   
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ . '/path/to/views');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
        'base_template_class'   => '\My\ProjectName\Here\Template',
    ));
```

**template.twig**

```
{% import "macros/forms.html" as forms %}
<ul>
{% for function in forms.DefinedFunctions %}
    <li>{{ function }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```